# L298 motor controller board

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]
Hello I have 2 questions:
A) do I have to remove any of the plastic casings that I have highlighted in order to make the motors move.
B) What is the purpose of the black plastic casing that I have pointed out?

Comment: Remove black casings? The jumper by the Vin and M1 headers is to control the on-board circuitry power—when enabled the on-board circuitry uses the 12V max Vin through a voltage regulator to run the 5V components, when disabled you need to supply a 5V source. The “black cases" on the left and right are protection diodes; if they’re removed bad things happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A) do I have to remove any of the plastic casings that I have highlighted in order to make the motors move.

Those aren't "casings", those are diodes. They are part of the circuit and must be left alone.

> B) What is the purpose of the black plastic casing that I have pointed out?

That is a "jumper" and is used to connect the +5V pin to the internal 5V regulator so the board can be run from just the 12V input power supply. Remove that if, and only if, you want to supply 5V to the board separately from elsewhere.